# Streaming H.264 + AAC to RTMP server with Gstreamer

Tags: streaming, h.264, gstreamer, aac

I have a set of files:

*audio_X.aac:*

```
audio/mpeg, framed=(boolean)false, mpegversion=(int)2, stream-format=(string)adts, level=(string)2, profile=(string)lc, channels=(int)1, rate=(int)44100
```

*video_X.h264:*

```
video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream
```

My goal is to combine those files into RTMP stream suitable for publishing on flash server like Nginx or Flusonic etc ..

My pipeline is (GSTREAMER 0.10 based):

```
appsrc_v -> h264parse -> flvmux -> rtmpsink  
appsrc_a -> aacparse -> faad ->faac  -> flvmux -> rtmpsink
```

I got a media stream but it has only Video part.

Can you please advise me what i am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

For such purposes you can use [gst-rtsp-server](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/modules/gst-rtsp-server.html). It can get 2 separate streams and serve RTSP clients as a server.

But it's a RSTP, not RTMP!

In such case you will have to restream this RSTP from `gst-rtsp-server` through your media server. Media server have to pull data from `gst-rtsp-server` app.